# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: APP_ENV environment variable is not defined

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, environment, symfony4, production-environment

I am deploying Symfony 4 project on production.
Created .env file with a content:

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=0
```

Run composer:

```
$ composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

Getting error:

```
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException:
 APP_ENV environment variable is not defined.
 You need to define environment variables for
 configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer
 dependency to load variables from a .env file. in 
/var/www/symfony4_project/bin/console:20
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 {main}
!!    thrown in /var/www/symfony4_project/bin/console on line 20
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

Symfony documentation about deployment and environment setting is very narrow and foggy.

It is not clear where I should set the production environments.

From https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

sentence "If you decide to set real environment variables on production, the .env files will not be loaded if Symfony detects that a real APP_ENV environment variable exists and is set to prod."

Where should I look for this real APP_ENV existence?

As I found on stackoverflow and github, there are many questions realated, but not so many answers.

Thanks for help.

Comment: After deployment some more errors appeared. And

Comment: I deploed project and couldn't access it, i found, that symfony 4 needs apache2 bundle to run: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install `symfony/dotenv` composer package to load your **.env** file.
Take a look to the official documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html
The Dotenv Component parses .env files to make environment variables accessible.

Run `composer require symfony/dotenv` this should work.

Comment: Happy to help, could you vote and confirm my anwser please

Comment: Ahmed, I woted your answer. I need 15 points reputation, to make it visible. Thanks, one more time.

Comment: @fama23 is --dev required? original question is about prod deployment!

Comment: Nah, not required, I gonna remove from the answer. Dotenv should be installed for all the nev. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've got this error in prod since Flex 1.2 in 2019 and you don't want to use .env file but the environment variables of your system :

It's because of changes : 
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-flex-1-2 : 
**Please read Improved the handling of `.env` files** on blog

In order :

1. You have to push your **.env on git**, but only this **.env** file
2. **Developpers** will create **.env.local** to override **.env** file for dev
3. **symfony/dotenv** is in **require-dev** section of composer.json
4. When you want to deploy :

   1. Get the git repo (without /vendors, of course)
   2. Run `composer dump-env prod --empty` to generate a .env.local.php file
   3. Install your dependencies via `composer install --no-dev` [Other prod args]

You can now enjoy your prod env without **symfony/dotenv** composant installed.

Answer (score 0):

I need a little bit more information to solve your problem.

First of all - just to be sure: did you add the dotenv dependency to your composer as hinted in your debug message: composer require symfony/dotenv

Also, what kind of symfony installation is it? Just a basic symfony/skeleton? 
In generall if you just installed a basic symfony/sekleton or website-skeleton changing the value of APP_ENV in .env should work! But we'll work that out.

Please verify that you installed dotenv and provide the information I am looking for.

Comment: It is Symfony4. I don't know how to add dotenv dependency to the composer.